# What's the word for ‘the point at which an object loses balance’?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms, terminology

I'm trying to think of a formal word to describe the "tipping point" of an object.

This would be the same point at which an object would be perfectly balanced.

Comment: Formal words might be "unstable equilibrium state" or "a saddle point". Refer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_equilibrium for the Physics Details.

Comment: This is more complicated than you suggest.  A cube is stable sitting flat, astable if balanced on an edge, and unstable if somewhere between flat and balanced on edge.  Normally the "tipping point" would be regarded as the astable point -- less deflection and it will fall back to it's original flat position, more deflection and it will roll onto its side.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the **[center of gravity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass#Center_of_gravity)**?

> An object will balance when its center of gravity (the place where all of its mass, on the average, resides) is over the point of support. The larger the base, the more stable the object is.

Source - [Exploratorium](https://www.exploratorium.edu/xref/phenomena/balance_-_center__of_gravi.html)

Comment: I don't think this is correct. It is not the "point" where the object loses its balance. Center of gravity can be inside or even outside the object. An object will balance on a pivot point when the center of gravity is above or below that pivot point.

Answer (score 1):

A ***fulcrum*** is the ***pivot point*** for a lever; but it can also be used as the balancing point of an object.

> *Physics* the point on which an object balances or turns [[Macmillan]](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/fulcrum)

A simple diagram to illustrate:

[image]
*[bvg8science.wikispaces.com](https://bvg8science.wikispaces.com/file/view/lever_drawing.gif/419984728/lever_drawing.gif)*

Comment: +1 You beat me to it. I think the answer is *pivot point* or *balance point*. [*Fulcrum*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/fulcrum) can be used also. Here is an example from [Nasa](http://www.grc.nasa.gov/WWW/k-12/WindTunnel/Activities/balance_of_forces.html).

Comment: A fulcrum is an external object upon which a lever arm is placed and about which it  pivots- it is not part of the object itself.

Comment: Jim, that's very true, but depending on the specific idea being expressed, it may still be a useful concept. I should have provided a disclaimer, perhaps, but my goal was simply to provide a useful lead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but a fulcrum is not exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Sova: I improved your answer if you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

More like sliding than *tipping* and (metaphorically) more to do with an objects 'place' in a hierarchy; added to the top (of the pile), it falls to the bottom.

**Angle of Repose** -[Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_repose)

> the maximum angle at which an object can rest on an inclined plane without sliding down.

*If you have complaints; get in line, the suggestion box has reached an angle of repose.*

I wavered on posting this, until I saw it linked to the [tipping point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tipping_point) wiki. A single word may exist that is more concise, but I believe that ***tipping point* is the correct terminology.**

Answer (score -2):

**[disequilibrium](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disequilibrium)** ("a loss or lack of balance" -- [m-w.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disequilibrium)) is the perfect fit I believe.

Comment: Why the downvotes?